Luther's summary of Psalm 83
In Weimar's edition of Luther's work, Luther supposedly summarized Psalm 83 as follows:

"God must be recognized and honored by all creatures, whether by grace or, contrary to the will, in damnation."

I'm trying to locate that quotation in the original German work.

Have searched through some of the Luther Library Publishing Ministry for Luther's work on the Psalms, as translated from the German, but have drawn a blank. There is such a wealth of information on this, I could only scan two books on the Psalms in p.d.f. format.  If you have not already done so, you may find what you are after if you look at https://www.lutheranlibrary.org/545-tholuck-psalms/  and many other related links  about the Psalms on that web-site.

Thanks so much Anne!
